# Rails re-formatting my datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a big query, which collects a collection of models, and I need to format the timestamps in the following manner: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS.MSZ`

So, my query looks like:

```
models.select("(to_char(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || 'T' || to_char(created_at, 'HH24:MI:SS.MSZ')) AS created_at").as_json
```

But, when I get the result, I still get `created_at` field as a DateTime object.
Nevertheless, if I rename the field in something else, like `AS something_else`, then I have my required format.

How can I fix the problem, so that it will return created_at in my format, without going through the whole collection, and formatting each model ?

**UPDATE**

Database I am using is PostreSQL

I traced this behaviour back to ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoder. I use the gem `activesupport-json_encoder` because I need the setting `ActiveSupport.encode_big_decimal_as_string = false`, while since Rails 4.1 they by default are encoded as strings.

Now, this Encoder is encoding `created_at` and `updated_at` fields as ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.
Can I get rid of the latter somehow ?

Comment: Why do you need to format that in query itself?

Comment: Because as a result of this query I may have thousands, tens of thousands of models, and they are sent directly to controller. And the whole API is based on such datetime (time with zone) formats.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention - PostgreSQL

Comment: I don't have much experience with this encoder gem but it seems you can overload some of its encoding methods: https://github.com/rails/activesupport-json_encoder#json-serialization-for-custom-objects see if that helps.